# connect arduino uno to local server

Tags: database, arduino, localserver

I am working on a project for which I am using MS SQL server and using Windows authentication. I have made the database and HTML page both are connected.

Now I have to connect Arduino to my local server because I want to store the data coming from my sonar sensor into Arduino UNO to my database tables and show it on HTML page.

Arduino is on robot car and database is in my laptop I have to connect them remotely.

I know how to connect Arduino to web server but don't know how to connect to my local server. Arduino command to connect to server is `client.connect(ip,port)` or `client.connect(url,port)`. But I don't know my IP. My local host server URL is `localhost:30154\Home`.

Guide me how can i connect my Arduino UNO to my database.

Comment: Calling `ìpconfig` on your laptop should tell you what is your IP

Comment: it tells the ip that is provided by my isp but it does not takes me to my required page whos url is "localhost:30154\Home". i used visual studio 2013 and made c# project using master page. one of these pages has this url "localhost:30154\Home"

Comment: have you tried by replacing `localhost` by your IP? Have you configured your firewall to let port 30154 open?

Comment: localhost is an alias for your laptop's IP. `ipconfig.exe` should NOT show you a number your ISP know about; it's a local IP reachable from any machine on the same LAN as your laptop.

Answer (score 0):

localhost = 127.0.0.1

You can use ipconfig in Prompt to check the v4 protocol, which is your ip, but the problem is if the ip is not fixed.

*Você pode usar o ipconfig no Prompt para verificar o protocolo v4, qual é o seu ip, mas o problema é se o o ip não for fixo.*

Comment: You could explain in detail precisely where to utilize the loopback localhost.  You could explain in detail how/why to use ifconfig to check the IPv4 protocol.  You could explain in detail how to keep the IPv4 IP address fixed/stable/unchanging.  (You could even explain in detail how to solve the problem for DHCP-assigned dynamic IP address, but that would be going the extra mile above & beyond.)  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested a review due to you being a new contributor.  Your answer is appreciated & helpful.  This comment is intended to help you make a good answer excellent.